# Firebase notifications not received

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to get notifications I sent from the firebase console but I'm unable to get anything. No matter if the app is in foreground or background.

I already set up the FCM SDK in my app-level build.gradle file though.

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}
```

Thank you for helping me fix what's wrong.

Comment: Adding dependency not enough, https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: You need more than that. You need to have a google-services.json file under your app folder. Try to use the Android Studio's assistant (Tools -> Firebase) to setup corretly.

Comment: You  should read official guideline.

Comment: @GabrielCosta that's what I did. I set it up via the Firebase Assistant

Answer (score 0):

Just adding dependency isn't enough.

You need to implement FirebaseMessagingService to actually receive notifications.

follow this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive